# joining hundreds of irc channels socket dying (twitch)

Tags: python, sockets, chatbot, twitch

I'm trying to join hundreds of channels with my chatbot on twitch. However the socket gets connection was forcibly closed by the remote host error, my problem is I don't particularly know how to add multiple sockets so if one dies then I can rejoin the channels on that socket and continue, instead it closes the client and tries to join all of the channels again.

Here is my code:

```
import socket
import time
import errno

with open('channels.txt') as f:
    channel_list = f.readlines()

def connect():
    global sock
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect(('irc.chat.twitch.tv', 6667))



def sendRaw(data, log:bool=True):
    try:
        if log:
            print(f"sending raw: {data}")
        sock.send(bytes(data + '\r\n', 'utf-8'))
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EPIPE:
            pass


def joinchannel(channel):
    channel = "#" + channel.lower() if not channel.startswith("#") else channel.lower()
    sendRaw('JOIN ' + channel)


def login_and_join():
    sendRaw('PASS oauth:')  # less likely to leak
    sendRaw('NICK justinfan0987')
    # requests more information
    sendRaw('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/commands')
    sendRaw('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags')
    sendRaw('JOIN #turtoise')
    sendRaw('JOIN #nimbot0')
    sendRaw('JOIN #peeandpoob')

    for channel in channel_list:
        joinchannel(channel)

def loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        try:
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            decoded_data = data.decode("utf-8").split("\r\n")
            if decoded_data is None:
                print("no data")
            print(decoded_data)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

def run_channel_joiner():
    connect()
    login_and_join()
    loop()

run_channel_joiner()
```

And here are some channels to test with:
https://pastebin.com/avn0PVVg

Comment: Have you checked you're actually authenticating successfully? Are you responding to the `PONG`s? Are you receiving data faster than you can process it (because of the `sleep()`)?

Comment: I have responding for pongs on my other version and ive tried changing the sleep, sleeping is because I thought that it  was receiving too much data but i have tried tons of different variations of that example. The authentication is correct, it uses an anonymous connection so if you want to test it you dont need to setup a twitch account

Comment: Sleeping doesn't stop you receiving the data. Instead, the data just sits in a OS buffer until your program fetches it. Eventually the OS buffer fills up and the OS will reject new data from the server. At which point the server probably just gives up and closes the connection.

Comment: That is, sleeping is causing the disconnects. You *MUST* process the data you are sent in a timely manner. If you cannot do that, then reduce the number of channels you are connecting to.

Comment: the sleeping is not causing the disconnects I have removed all the sleeps and still getting the same error, the entire point of the post is to join a large amount of channels

Comment: That's over 7000 channels! Start off small and work your way up. With that many channels you won't be able to print stuff out anymore. You'll have to log stuff instead and review your log files as they are appended to. Once you get your basics working with a few channels, then you can try to handle something that big.

Comment: Further, documentation states a user/bot is rate-limited to joining at most 20 channels every 10 seconds https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc/guide#command--message-limits So you will have to write a multithreaded solution that slowly joins all your desired channels over at least an hour (assuming you are not verified). So likely the server is disconnecting you for trying to join too many channels too quickly.

Comment: hm, im pretty sure its not anything to do with ratelimits because I own a verified bot and I believe it might be the amount of data being received because I can join one channel but when I've stress tested it with 100 lines per second it ends up having the same error.  Ive tried threading it but that hasnt worked for me either.

Comment: Look at the documentation again. Even verified bots are rate limited to 2,000 JOINs per 10 seconds, and you're trying to join >7,000 as fast as you can. Second, this code in the question is not authenticating with the server, so how does it know it's a verified bot? It doesn't, and so will treat it like a regular bot.

Comment: Anonymous connections do not have rate limits, I have added a delay joining the channels every 1 second however like  I said it crashes when there is a lot of data, you can see for yourself if you dont believe me. Adding any sort of delays will not help because its crashing due to the amount of lines per second its receiving  from being in that many channels. I have tried with a verified bot account  with my oauth in but I obviously can not share my oauth so I put in the anonymous connection for people to be able to test it and see for themselves